# Access dashboard's time range and granularity from KQL

Tags: azure, azure-log-analytics, kql, azure-monitoring

I've added a chart using KQL and logs from Azure Log Analytics to a dashboard. I'm using `make-series` which works great but the catch is the following:

The logs I'm getting might not extend to the whole time range dictated by the dashboard. So basically I need access to the starttime/endtime (and time granularity) to make `make-series` cover the whole timerange.

e.g.

```
logs
| make-series
    P90 = percentile(Elapsed, 90) default = 0,
    Average = avg(Elapsed) default = 0
    // ??? need start/end time to use in from/to
    on TimeGenerated step 1m
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, it's not supported. There are some feedbacks about this feature: [Support for time granularity selected in Azure Portal Dashboard](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/357324-azure-monitor-application-insights/suggestions/37020748-support-for-time-granularity-selected-in-azure-por), and [Retrieve the portal time span and use it inside the kusto query](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/267889-azure-monitor-log-analytics/suggestions/37335769-retrieve-the-portal-time-span-and-use-it-inside-th).

And some people provided workarounds in [the first feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/357324-azure-monitor-application-insights/suggestions/37020748-support-for-time-granularity-selected-in-azure-por), you can give it a try.

Comment: Look's like it's a fundamental feature that's missing. Thanks for the info.

Comment: The links are broken

Comment: Updated link here and it is marked as completed. However doesn't work for me https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/1b2e4ce0-aa25-ed11-9db1-000d3a4d91bc

Answer (score 0):

I posted on another question on this subject - you can do a bit of a hack in your KQL to get this working: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73064218/5785878